# Upload images to server one by one - Android

Tags: android, image, list, loops, file-upload

I am wondering how could I achieve uploading a list of images to the server, but most importantly one by one.

Bellow is the code that contains a map with the list of the images, I would like to loop through the list and upload one image at a time.

If possible, without the use of a Timer. I would be really grateful for any advice.

```
sendOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : imgPathAndNameMap.entrySet()) {
                                uploadPhoto(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                            }
                     }
                  }
              });


public void uploadPhoto(String imgName, String imgPath){

        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30000;
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        //check image size
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, opts);

        //get the original size
        int orignalHeight = opts.outHeight;
        int orignalWidth = opts.outWidth;

        Log.w("", orignalHeight + "x" + orignalWidth);

        if(orignalHeight > 2000 || orignalWidth > 2000){
            byte[] bitmapdata = resize(imgPath, orignalHeight, orignalWidth, opts, bp);
            params.put("zipFile", new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata), imgName);
        } else {
            File theZip = new File(imgPath);
            try {
                Log.w("", imgPath );
                params.put("zipFile", theZip);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        params.put("name", name.getText());


            client.post("http://www.lab.com/upload-image.php", params,
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
                            if (arg0 == 0) {

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
                            try {
                                ((PreloaderDialog) progressDialog).passValues(
                                        position, length);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Multumim pentru Comanda!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Your best bet would be Volley - Just google that.

Comment: You can use AsyncTask,OnPost method again you can start the asyncTask with different image without interacting with UI Thread.Otherwise you may face UI Freeze problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of a better solution, I have set up the loopj Async Http Client's onSuccess() method to trigger the parent method automatically after a picture is uploaded. In the same time I increment the position of the upcoming file inside the array I use to store the path to each image.

It works great, hope to help out others having the same issue.

```
public void uploadPhoto(){           

        String iPath = files[position];
        String iName = imgName[position];

        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30000;
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);


       File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
         try {
              params.put("imageFile", imageFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    

     params.put("position", position);        
     params.put("name", name.getText());


      client.post("http://www.yoursite.com/upload-img.php", params,
              new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                   @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
                            uploadPhoto();
                        }

                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                     position ++;
                     if(position < files.length) {
                           uploadPhoto();
                          } else {
                           progress.dismiss();
                           Toast.makeText(context, "Thanks for your order!",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To post your image one by one you probably need to use synchronous request, but you can do that on UI thread. So you should do that in backgound. For instance you can use an [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Handler.postDelayed()`

Comment: you should suggest where